# It's possible create a custom delegate in AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate

i want know if it's possible create a custom delegate in the AppDelegate class, like in this way for instance:

```
@protocol AppDelegateDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)finishSync:(BOOL)success;

@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AppDelegateDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

it's possible create something like this? to notify the classes that are registered for this delegate?

**EDIT**
How i can use the Delegate? for example if i do this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <AppDelegateDelegate>

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MasterViewController

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  appController.customDelegate = self;

}
```

in i stay only in that view works, but for example if i switch in SecondViewController that have the same code to implement the delegate, the delegate don't works anymore neither in the MasterViewController...what i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, That is fine. You can create delegates anywhere you want and use it anywhere by importing that class. There are no restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I think I have answered one question of yours previously. I follow most of the questions in SO. :)

Comment: if i want use then the delegate in other view, how i can use it? i have to do this? AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appController.customDelegate = self; anywhere in the code? or i have to declare the appController in the header file in the @interface?

Comment: because i notice that in that way works, but when i switch in another view that have the same code to declare the delegate, the delegate don't work anymore...

Comment: @Piero, What exactly are you trying to achieve using this delegate in appdelegate? Why do you need it there and not in some other class? If you are planning to use in multiple classes, you shouldn't use appdelegate for this, since it has only one instance, it cant have more than one delegate like this. I recommend you to post this as a new question with the details of what you are trying to achieve. We can suggest someother way for this. Since this question is about can we use appdelegate for protocols, it shouldnt be mixed with the other questions.